# zoom in & zoom out image with the help of slider

Tags: jquery

I want to make a slider that zoom in or out image like :-
http://test.dpetroff.ru/jquery.iviewer/test/
or
http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/input/slider

please help me

Comment: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Google it.. You'll get many plugins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very nice jQuery plugin [T Squares Image Zoom](http://tsquares.net/index.html). It will definitely help you to solve the problem.

**EDIT**

When using the plugin you can specify many parameters e.g.

- Mouse wheel enabled / disabled for zooming in / out
- Wheel Step
- Button Step
- Zoom Cursor and many more.

Answer (score 1):

Try [**jQuery Gzoom Plugin**](http://lab.gianiaz.com/jquery/gzoom/)

It is an excellent jQuery image zoom plugin with a very useful features like click on plus and minus to zoom, drag the slider to zoom Zoom using mousewheel hover the image, moving mouse hover the image change the pan, click on the image to show in lightbox style and others.

Comment: this plugin fulfill my all requirements but this show jQuery error. Can u please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Could [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) it, if possible?

Comment: It shows jQuery.fn.gzoom = function(settings) is not define. To solve that I use jQuery.noConflict(); After that it shows var hiSrc = ig.attr("src").replace(settings.re, settings.replace); is undefined. Please help me solve issue.